# Getstream can not get reaction if user token has permission scope

Tags: permissions, feed, getstream-io

I'm using Getstream for my feed application.
But I want to have my own permission management system, an user can't follow a feed group without call my backend api but he can read some feed groups by call Stream Api directly.
So, at backend, I generate an user token with a permission scope like this.

```
{
      "resource": "*",
      "action": "read",
      "feed_id": "user1"
}
```

So when the user want to add activity or add reactions he must call my backend api. My backend will call Stream API to add them.

My issue: with this permission scope, he can't get reactions list directly from Stream API even if his reactions of his activities.

```
clientUser.reactions.filter({ activity_id: "f480ec6d-e538-11eb-92fd-128a130028af" })
            .then(data => console.log("filter reactions success", data))
            .catch(err => console.log("filter reactions error", err.error.detail))
```

This is my pain, I need your helps.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are a default set of permissions in place that cater for the most common scenarios.  As you've rightly pointed out, you can circumvent these by calling a backend that has admin access and you restrict things yourself with your own logic.

You can email the getstream support to change the default permissions because these are not manageable from the dashboard. And is mentioned here on thier site: https://getstream.io/activity-feeds/docs/react-native/auth_and_permissions/?language=javascript#how-to-change-permissions